# Why am I getting 4.5 VDC output?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

With this simple op-amp circuit R1 = 3.6k ohms and R2 = 4.7k ohms. With my input at zero (grounded) I am getting an output of 4.5 VDC.  I am trying to get a near zero output with 0 VDC input. Do I need to run the 741 on a split supply ? Should I choose a different opamp?                  The gain should be about 2.3.  With a 5 VDC input the output is near 12VDC as planned.  Can anyone tell me why I am getting 4.5 VDC output with a 0 VDC input?

Comment: Try making v- -12 (or even -2V) rather than ground.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a 741?... there are much better opamps out there. I use LM324s, they have the same problem but are cheaper, robust and you get 4 opamps for the price of one 741 in 1 offs (ok that's a quad opamp.. but still... better IMHO).

Comment: Even an LM324 is arguably dated and cost more than its worth, depending on the requirements. My go-to general-purpose op-amp is the MCP6004, quad op-amp for less than $1/unit in small quantities, rail-to-rail I/O. Low max supply voltage, though.

Answer (score 6):

You need a negative power rail if you expects inputs and outputs to get anywhere near zero volts.

The 741 opamp is not a "rail to rail" device: -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing your op amp. A 741 is not designed to operate with either input or output near the power supply voltages. For that you need what is called a rail-to-rail op amp.

The "simplest" fix is to provide another 12 volt supply, and connect -12 volts to pin 4, with the two supplies tied together at ground.

Answer (score 1):

The 741 doesn't can't handle input voltage close to either power rail and can't drive the output close to either rail. Apparently when you tie the input to the negative rail it shuts off.

Two options:

- Give it a negative voltage on pin 4.
- Replace with a device that will accept input voltages down to negative rail.

The second option is usually the easier.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are attempting to operate a crappy op-amp at near the V- rail. You will need to consider providing a -12V supply to the V- pin.

Comment: Well, not crappy, exactly. They were a lot easier to use than 709s.  I've done useful stuff with 741s. Granted, that was 30 years ago, but still...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that yes, you do need to add in a negative supply in order to amplify voltages down to 0 volts.  The data sheet for the part recommends supply voltages from +/-20V down to +/-5V.  Thus the +12V/0V single-ended configuration barely meets the 10V minimum power supply span. However the circuit as shown has the op amp driven too close to the supply voltage rails.
This 741 part was a significant innovation in its day but there are "modern" innovations that it does not have. Among these are rail-to-rail inputs and rail-to-rail outputs.  A glance at the part schematic shown in the TI spec for the National LM741, for example shows that the outputs can only attain voltages within about a base-emitter forward biased junction (.65-.7) of the negative (or positive) rail because of the common-emitter transistors used for output.

On the input side, the stack of differential pairs used for amplification, bias and offset voltage compensation mean that the inverting and non-inverting inputs (at the top of the stack) probably can't be driven closer to ground than about 2V common mode without some kind of adverse performance.  [In fact some differential amps will stop being inverting amplifiers and become non-inverting amplifiers whenever the inputs are driven more negative than the negative rail (e.g. LM139 comparator).]    In the data sheet, due to these contributions from the inputs and output,  the  output voltage swing is not guaranteed to get any closer to the rails than 3V at 10K load or even 5V at 2K load, although typical values are 1V and 2V, respectively.
The voltage follower configuration you have shown implements the nominal relation Vi=Vo Ri/(Ri+Rf) (Ri=3.6K and Rf=4.7K), assuming that no current flows into the 741 input pin and that the op amp drives its output so that the inverting input follows very closely to the non-inverting input. This simply expresses the voltage divider relationship of gain-setting resistor Ri and feedback resistor Rf.  Thus when we get to the 2V limit of the inverting input from ground, the non-inverting input will also be at about 2V but the output pin will be at Vo=Vi (Ri+Rf)/Ri = 2V (3.6K+4.7K)/3.6K = 4.61V.  A simulation of the 741 schematic from TI, using generic transistors, in fact showed the output clamping at 4.83V on its trajectory towards ground, and the inverting input clamping at 2.1V, at exactly the divider ratio.  This goes along with what you are seeing as well.

Changing the return for the voltage divider to one half of the supply range doesn't correct the situation because you are still driving the inputs too close to the rails.  Only by changing the negative rail to provide some cushion for the inputs can you attain the bottom of the output range you want; even 2.2V would be enough.