# Opamp output saturates at 1.7V even though rail voltage is 5V

Tags: operational-amplifier, saturation, single-supply-op-amp

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKw6Zp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am working on following circuit on a 4 layer PCB. The sensor gives output from 0.5V to 4.5V and has frequency response of 19 Hz based on the specifications. The circuit is designed to give 3.375V output when sensor is 4.5V. However the Opamp is saturating at 1.7 volts.

I have done the following:
1. Replaced the Opamp and the resistors around it, but it is same behavior.
2. Checked if it is getting the correct supply and input and all seems to be in order.
3. I could not check current drawn as all components are SMD. LP2950-50 which powers the TLV522 can source 100mA at 5V.

And the most baffling part was that it was working for couple of weeks before this behavior suddenly started. I am trying to rectify the behavior but I am at a loss of what could be causing it.

My question is:
What could be causing the saturation of the output of the second op amp? Do I have a common mode problem?

Datasheets: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv522.pdf
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp2950-50.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting 4.5 VDC output?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206916/why-am-i-getting-4-5-vdc-output)

Comment: @MattYoung  The [TLV522](http://www.ti.com/product/TLV522) used by the O.P. is a rail-to-rail OpAmp (unlike the one in that other question).

Comment: @NickAlexeev Maybe Mr. O.P. should provide some datasheet links.

Comment: Try shorting R4 or at least bypass it with 10nF (across the resistor). Also, measure the output voltage with 10K in series, and very close to the op-amp output. And nothing else connected (!)

Comment: Where is the other end of R7 connected?  Which OP-amp's output is saturating?  (What is happening on the output of U5-A?)

Comment: You could make your schematic more clear by showing the supply voltages and how the feedback for U5-B is connected.

Comment: "**it was working for couple of weeks** before this behaviour suddenly started" - that tells you it's not a design fault. But since that is all you have given us - how do you expect us to diagnose the fault? Any ideas we had would be pure speculation, whereas you just need to take a few measurements with a multimeter.

Comment: Why do you need U5-B at all? What's the range for your analogue input on the MCU?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a behavior which suddenly started for no reason is unlikely to be reproducible and cannot be explained by the info provided in the question.

Comment: Is this on a PCB or breadboard

Comment: I have edited the post to show the feedback link which was missing before. The supply voltage is 5 V DC from LP2950-50 which can source 100mA current. The circuit is assembled on a 4 layer PCB.

Comment: @Finbarr, the dual opamp was chosen because the TI advice about interfacing with ADCs recommends it. The ADC can take up to 3.3 V so just to reduce the voltage two opamps are not needed. The A is only a non inverting voltage follower and B does actual reduction.

Comment: @MattYoung; Datasheet for TLV522 is here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv522.pdf 
Datasheet for LP2950-50 (the 5V LDO supply to OPAMP) is here:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp2950-50.pdf

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I will try to assemble the same circuit on a breadboard and see if the same behaviour is repeated.

Comment: It could be caused by some short. Which opamp saturates at 1.7V? U5-A or U5-B?

Comment: @nick1256 Add that to the schematic! No one likes to plow though comments to get such data.

Comment: @nick1256 Thanks for being cooperative! I'm going to vote for reopen, and will be happy to take a look on the results of your experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the schematic you provided, there are two major issues,

1. No power is supplied to the op-amps
2. No negative feedback is provided around op-amp U5-B

Your text contradicts what you presented in the schematic, but it's much easier to understand a schematic than text, so I've answered based on your schematic.

Comment: Photon, thanks for the comments. The opamps are powered using LP2950-50 IC which gives 5V output from a 12V regulated supply. The negative feedback is through R7, I made the mistake in drawing the schematic, it was my first time on stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pin point the issue yesterday.
The opamp circuit above is interfaced with the ADC of MSP432P401M microcontroller on a 4 layer PCB. One of the reasons we chose TLV522 was that it can give rail to rail output and ADC does not need very high current. The whole board is assembled. The sensor we are interfacing is a capacitance based tilt sensor which has its own circuit which will give the output in DC form.

The reason this was happening was because the ADC pin was damaged. We were checking the connectivity of all components on the PCB and the opamp out to ground showed only 30 ohm resistance. So we disconnected the ADC pin by lifting it up and the opamp out to ground showed open connection on a DMM. So after that I checked the ADC pin to ground connectivity and it shows 30ohm resistance. This is all in complete power off state. So I think something damaged the ADC and so it was drawing too much current which was loading the OPAMP.

Now we are cutting the track and soldering the opamp output to ADC of the second bank by external copper wire. This will do for testing purposes but if the issue repeats then we will need to work on it.